# alias package names in Common Lisp

Tags: package, common-lisp

I'm using an external package in Common Lisp for a project; I want to be able to use the package but alias it to a shorter name, similar to how in Clojure I could do

```
(require '[unnecessarily-long-package-name :as ulpn])
```

In order to avoid naming conflicts, I'd rather not do this:

```
(defpackage #:my-package
  (:use #:cl #:other-package))

(in-package :my-package)

(take-over-world "pinky" "brain")
```

where `other-package` defines `take-over-world`. I could just type the full qualified package name every time:

```
(defpackage #:my-package
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package :my-package)

(other-package:take-over-world "pinky" "brain")
```

but in my case the package I'm importing has an unnecessarily long name. Is there a way I can use `other-package` as

```
(op:take-over-world "pinky" "brain")
```

by aliasing it to `op`? I wasn't able to find anything like this in the relevant chapter in Practical Common Lisp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to do it now (since 2018 maybe?) is with Package-Local Nicknames (PLN), now available in most implementations.

```lisp
(defpackage :mypackage
  (:use :cl)
  (:local-nicknames (:nickname :original-package-name)
                    (:alex :alexandria)
                    (:re :cl-ppcre)))

(in-package :mypackage)

;; You can use :nickname instead of :original-package-name
(nickname:some-function "a" "b")
```

(edit) And, from anywhere, you can use `(uiop:add-package-local-nickname :nickname :package)`.

When `nicknames` were global, PLNs are now local to *your* package and don't pollute the global namespace.

- https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/packages.html#package-local-nicknames-pln
- https://github.com/phoe/trivial-package-local-nicknames compatibility library (should not be needed anymore)

Comment: You need ASDF 3.3.5 for PLN, here's a one-liner to get it: https://github.com/lisp-tips/lisp-tips/issues/40

Answer (score 23):

In standard Common Lisp packages have global *nicknames*. You can give a package one or more nicknames in the `DEFPACKAGE` definition:

```
(defpackage "LONGER-FOO"
  (:use "CL")
  (:nicknames "LF"))
```

For existing packages in plain Common Lisp use [RENAME-PACKAGE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rn_pkg.htm):

`rename-package package new-name &optional new-nicknames => package-object`

**Example**:

```
CL-USER 1 > (defpackage "LONG-FOO" (:use "CL"))
#<The LONG-FOO package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 2 > (let ((package (find-package "LONG-FOO")))
              (rename-package package
                              (package-name package)
                              (adjoin "FOO"
                                      (package-nicknames package)
                                      :test #'string=)))
#<The LONG-FOO package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>
```

**As a function**:

Notice that we want to keep the existing nicknames by default.

```
(defun add-nickname (package nickname
                     &key (keep-existing-nicknames-p t))
  (when (stringp package)
    (setf package (find-package package)))
  (check-type package package)
  (check-type nickname string)
  (rename-package package
                  (package-name package)
                  (if keep-existing-nicknames-p
                      (adjoin nickname (package-nicknames package)
                              :test #'string=)
                    (list nickname))))
```

**Then we can call**:

```
(add-nickname "LONG-FOO" "BAZ")
```

Comment: I ignored this answer a few days ago, because it seemed too complicated to me. My short answer to the original question would be: `(rename-package :original-package-name :original-package-name '(alias))`.

Comment: The short answer is however incorrect because it removes existing nicknames.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. I used http://www.cliki.net/cl-package-aliases in my CL days, but it's pretty outdated ATM. Though other solutions are listed here https://github.com/avodonosov/local-package-aliases